# How to speed up the sqlite insert operation for large data

Tags: performance, sqlite, insert

I wanted to insert the data in qslite3 database in linux script. The code below is working and inserting the data. But it take very much time to insert data when data rows are in thousands. How to reduce the time to insert large data.

I have googled and found execute and commit; but does not know how to implement. Any idea please?

```
local files=( $( find  -L -type f -print | sed 's/^..//' ))                 
for file in ${files[@]};do          
    sqlite3 "${dbpath}/${dbname}" "INSERT into files (files) values ('${file}');"                       
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try using transactions. But i don't know if this works with sqlite3.exe.

Comment: I am on Linux and does not know how to use these commands in Linux Terminal.

Comment: Try the commands "BEGIN TRANSACTION" and "COMMIT TRANSACTION". you can also Google this. I think you can execute this commands when you Pass them aß arguments to your sqlite3.exe